# Create a single mutator for multple fields using laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I want to create a mutator that will serve me for several fields of a table. I have several fields called: h1, h2, h3 and other fields.

For now I have a mutator for each field (h1, h2 and h3) that works as follows:

If there is a value, that value is inserted in the field h1, h2 or h3, but if not, a 0 is inserted

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Custom extends Model
{
   protected $fillable = array(
      'h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'other_field', 'other_field2'
   );

  public function setH1Attribute($value)
  {
    if(!empty($value))
        $this->attributes['h1'] = $value;
    else
        $this->attributes['h1'] = 0;
  }

  public function setH2Attribute($value)
  {
    if(!empty($value))
        $this->attributes['h2'] = $value;
    else
        $this->attributes['h2'] = 0;
  }

  public function setH3Attribute($value)
  {
    if(!empty($value))
        $this->attributes['h3'] = $value;
    else
        $this->attributes['h3'] = 0;
  }
}
```

How can I create a single mutator that speeds up this task but only for the fields h1, h2, h3  and that I ignore the other fields?

Thanks for the help

Comment: You can use the [magic `__set()` and `__get()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) methods.

Answer (score 3):

@Ohgodwhy has a good answer, but I would make sure if you are overwriting `__set()` to default to Laravel functionality:

```
public function __set($key, $value)
{
    if(in_array($key, ['h1', 'h2', 'h3'])){
        //do your mutation
    } else {
        //do what Laravel normally does
        $this->setAttribute($key, $value);
    }
}
```

Source of Model: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1485

Comment: This is thoughtful.

Answer (score 1):

Like Alex said, you can use `__set()`, check if the property is fillable, and then set the attribute based on the name and value.

```
public function __set($name, $value) 
{
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->fillable) {
        $this->attributes[$name] = !empty($value) ? $value : 0;
    }
}

public function __get($name) 
{
    return $this->attributes[$name];
}
```

Use it like this:

```
$custom->h1 = 'Hello';
$custom->h2 = '';

echo $custom->h1; // produces 'Hello';
echo $custom->h2; // produces 0;
```

Note that you should also handle conditions when it's not fillable, and getting properties that don't exist, as well. This is just a basic implementation.